# Add grey background to inline text

Tags: highlighting

I want to make several words with a grey background `like this` within normal text? Like with `\colorbox{yellow}{\lstinline{some text here}}` but grey instead of yellow. How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `yellow` with `gray`, i.e. `\colorbox{gray}{...}`? You could also define your own, lighter gray color (e.g. `\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.89}`).

Comment: Simply with `\colorbox{grey}{ ... }`. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @chrisma This works "\colorbox{yellow}{sadef}". This "\colorbox{gray}{sdfASDF}" gives error "Undefined color `gray'. \colorbox{gray}{sdfASDF}". This "\colorbox{grey}{sdfASDF}" gives error "Undefined color `grey'. \colorbox{grey}{sdfASDF}".

Comment: @chrisma This works "\colorbox{yellow}{sadef}". This "\colorbox{gray}{sdfASDF}" gives error "Undefined color `gray'. \colorbox{gray}{sdfASDF}". This "\colorbox{grey}{sdfASDF}" gives error "Undefined color `grey'. \colorbox{grey}{sdfASDF}".

Comment: Sorry cannot format comment properly.

Comment: Did you load `xcolor`?

Comment: @chrisma Why did you delete your answer? It was fine!

Comment: @Bernard I added `xcolor` and it works with `\colorbox{gray}{sdfASDF}`. How can I get more light grey? `\colorbox{light-gray}{sdfASDF}`and `\colorbox{light-grey}{sdfASDF}` does not works.

Comment: Use `lightgray` or define an own color (see documentation on how to do that).

Comment: @TeXnician `\colorbox{lightgrey}{sdfASDF}` does not works too.

Comment: That's why I wrote `lightgray`. a instead of e.

Comment: @TeXnician That works. Thank you.  Write the answer if you want and I will except it

Comment: If you load xcolor with option `svgnames`, you have access to other shades of grey, such as `Gainsboro` or `WhiteSmoke`. Also you can mix colours.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. That works. If you wish you can make an answer and I will upvote. If you will not I will add the answer with your suggestion later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you write in your question you use `\colorbox`. As the first argument is simply a color name you need to exchange `yellow` for `gray` or one of the other defined colors from `xcolor` (first column is name):

```
\definecolorset{rgb/hsb/cmyk/gray}{}{}%
 {red,1,0,0/0,1,1/0,1,1,0/.3;%
  green,0,1,0/.33333,1,1/1,0,1,0/.59;%
  blue,0,0,1/.66667,1,1/1,1,0,0/.11;%
  brown,.75,.5,.25/.083333,.66667,.75/0,.25,.5,.25/.5475;%
  lime,.75,1,0/.20833,1,1/.25,0,1,0/.815;%
  orange,1,.5,0/.083333,1,1/0,.5,1,0/.595;%
  pink,1,.75,.75/0,.25,1/0,.25,.25,0/.825;%
  purple,.75,0,.25/.94444,1,.75/0,.75,.5,.25/.2525;%
  teal,0,.5,.5/.5,1,.5/.5,0,0,.5/.35;%
  violet,.5,0,.5/.83333,1,.5/0,.5,0,.5/.205}%
\definecolorset{cmyk/rgb/hsb/gray}{}{}%
 {cyan,1,0,0,0/0,1,1/.5,1,1/.7;%
  magenta,0,1,0,0/1,0,1/.83333,1,1/.41;%
  yellow,0,0,1,0/1,1,0/.16667,1,1/.89;%
  olive,0,0,1,.5/.5,.5,0/.16667,1,.5/.39}
\definecolorset{gray/rgb/hsb/cmyk}{}{}%
 {black,0/0,0,0/0,0,0/0,0,0,1;%
  darkgray,.25/.25,.25,.25/0,0,.25/0,0,0,.75;%
  gray,.5/.5,.5,.5/0,0,.5/0,0,0,.5;%
  lightgray,.75/.75,.75,.75/0,0,.75/0,0,0,.25;%
  white,1/1,1,1/0,0,1/0,0,0,0}
```

---

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

werwe \colorbox{lightgray}{sdfASDF} wqerwqe

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added an example. Please approve if you agree.

Answer (score 8):

The `svgnames` option of `xcolor` defines a number of shades of grey. Furthermore, you can mix colours easily. Here's a demo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

 \colorbox{lightgray}{sdfASDF} \medskip

 \colorbox{Gainsboro}{sdfASDF} \medskip

 \colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{sdfASDF}\medskip

 \colorbox{WhiteSmoke}{sdfASDF} \medskip

 \colorbox{WhiteSmoke!70!Lavender}{sdfASDF}

\end{document}
```

Explanation (valid for 2 colours): `Gainsboro!60!Lavender` means 60 % of Gainsboro and 40% of Lavender.

`Gainboro!70` would mean 70 % of Gainsboro and 30 % of white.

[image]